# CasperJS - Form fill() returns a 401

Tags: casperjs

I'm trying to test a web page that has basic authentication.

This is what I have so far:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug'
});

casper.options.viewportSize = {width: 1366, height: 667};

casper.start();

casper.open( 'http://internal/page.php', {
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic '+btoa('username:password')
    }
}).then(function(response) {
    this.fill('form[action="page2.php"]', {
        cattype: 'BLAH2',
        needdate: '04/21/2014'
    }, true);
});
casper.then(function() {
    this.capture('screenshot-form-entry.png');
});
casper.run(function() {
    this.exit();
});
```

The page opens properly (no authentication problem).

The form fields are set properly.

The problem is the form submission.

It says **status=fail**.

I look at the server logs and it gives a 401.

***Why are the credentials not passed along to the form submission?
Or maybe the question should be, how can a I get the credentials passed along?***

Comment: Did you try with the bool in the fill method to false instead of true? And then click (this.click(...) ) on the submit button.

Comment: I have tried that as well. Same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple of days of digging I'll answer my own question with what I found.

I'm not sure if this is a bug or the way it's supposed to work.

For basic authorization, you have to set **username/password** in the **pageSettings**.

Here is the changed code.

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
    pageSettings: {
       userName: 'uid',
       password: 'pwd'
    }
});

casper.start();

casper.open( 'http://internal/page.php').then(function(response) {
    this.fill('form[action="page2.php"]', {
        cattype: 'BLAH2',
        needdate: '04/21/2014'
    }, true);
});
casper.then(function() {
    this.capture('screenshot-form-entry.png');
});
casper.run(function() {
    this.exit();
});
```